# Swift camera zoom to 0.5x in wide angle lens

Tags: ios, swift, camera

I have zoom feature working(1x onwards) for custom camera implemented using AVFoundation. This is fine till the iPhone X models. But I wanted to have 0.5x zoom in iPhone 11.
Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not I understood the question correctly. I don't think you can achieve a 0.5x zoom only using the wide-angle camera.

If you refer to the 0.5x zoom as in the native iOS camera, you achieve that by switching from the wide-angle camera to the ultra wide-angle camera.

I think you have two options:

1. You can switch directly to the ultrawide camera via a button or so (below a short snippet for selecting the camera and assigning it to your active device.

   ```swift
   if let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInUltraWideCamera, for: .video, position: .back) {
               videoDevice = device
           } else {
               fatalError("no back camera")
           }
   ```
2. On supported devices like the iphone11 you can use the .builtInDualCamera as your active device. In this case, the system will automatically switch between the different cameras depending on the zoomFactor. Of course, on iPhone 11pro and 12pro series, you can even use .buildInTripleCamera to go to 2x zoom. You can even check for when the switch happens, please refer to the link below for more information.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/3153003-virtualdeviceswitchovervideozoom